# What are the last letter of the LogRecord format

Tags: python, logging

So I've been using the logging module for a while now, and I am not fully understanding what **the last letter** of the LogRecord format does, per example:

```
%(lineno)d
%(message)s
%(asctime)s
%(created)f
%(message)s
```

You can see that they have a different letter after the parentheses, I want to know what are the differences between those and the purpose of those, they must exist for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

These are old-style string formatters. You can read about it here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting

Specifically in this case

- `d` = format as integer decimal number
- `s` = string
- `f` = format as floating point decimal number

Comment: Appreciate it, so these are just like placeholders? Ohhh thanks you